# restricting mobile data for certain apps on Samsung Galaxy phone

Tags: samsung, android-11

Previously I was running Google Pixel OS on a rooted phone. I got tired of not being able to download certain apps due to the phone being rooted (netflix, banking, etc) so I decided to get a cheap Samsung (Galaxy A32 Purchased in Korea)

On this phone I cannot find any settings for restricting certain apps from using mobile data like I was able to do on the Pixel OS. Is this feature standard for all android phones or is it disabled on some OS's? Its really annoying because I don't pay for a lot of data, but I don't want to forget and accidentally start watching YT when I think I am on wifi but actually using mobile data.

Comment: See if this helps https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/04/13/block-internet-access-for-specific-apps-android/

Comment: hmm yeah I guess I have to go through a third party app because the "disable mobile data" toggle is nowhere to be found. Probably a sneaky way for the carriers to increase their data fees on people.